Comparing two unequal data frames in R by their IDS
I have two unequal data frames in R that I want to join (by a right join) and then compare them row by row based on whether their infromation matches
Data Frame 1
enter image description here
Data Frame 2
enter image description here
I have joined them, a right join
N<-join(Test_1, Test_2,  type = "right", by="ID")
This is the result
enter image description here
Now I want to compare if they match row by row based on the ID number and create a new column with yes or no
If I need to add any other details please let me know.
I am expecting to create an additional column with 'Yes' or 'No' based on whether the rows match BY IDs
For instance, ID 651 would be No because they don't match based on the information in their columns

From R-tag description: “ Please use minimal reproducible examples others can run using copy & paste. Show desired output entirely. Use dput() for data & specify all non-base packages with library(). Don't embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks instead.”

You can create a variable that check the equality of the fields, for example:
library(dplyr)


joined_df <- 
  data.frame(id = c(650,651,670), field1 = c(1,2,3), field1.1 = c(1,2,4), field2 = c(1,2,3), field2.1 = c(1,7,5))

joined_df %>%
  mutate(equal_df = (field1 == field1.1) & (field2 == field2.1) )



These work as well
Test_1 %>% 
  full_join(Test_2, by = 'ID') %>%
  mutate(match_yn = c('no_match', 'match')[1 + (`Field 1.x` == `Field 1.y`& `Field 2.x` == `Field 2.y` )])

Test_1 %>% 
  inner_join(Test_2, by = 'ID') %>%
  mutate(match_yn = c('no_match', 'match')[1 + (`Field 1.x` == `Field 1.y`& `Field 2.x` == `Field 2.y` )])

